# How do I add additional classes inside pre compiled apk

Tags: android, class

The thing is, I have an android rom which has an application I am trying to port. But some of the classes that the application needs are inside framework. I already have classes both in smali (by decompiling the classes.dex inside framework.jar through smali-backsmali tool) and java (through the source code) formats.
But my question is, how do I implement/add them inside apk?
I know classes are present in classes.dex.

I have tried following->

1) Decompiled apk with apktool and added class files (with smali format) with respective paths inside the smali folder which appears after decompiling apk.
Problem in the step-> When I recompile apk, somehow the classes I added myself dont appear when I compile the apk. To elaborate more clearly->
Suppose by default, the smali folder of decompiled apk contains X class. And I add Y class (by simply copying the Y.smali file inside the decompiled smali folder). But when I recompile apk, the classes.dex of recompiled apk contains only X class and Y class is still missing.

2) Extract classes.dex from apk archive and use backsmali to get classout folder. Then copy additional needed classes inside it and then again repack it into classes.dex. Then I put back the new classes.dex back to apk archive (I rename the "new-classes.dex" to "classes.dex" and replace the one inside apk archive with newer one I just created).
Problem in this step-> It gives the error in logcat as-

```
E/dalvikvm(2373): Dex cache directory isn't writable: /data/dalvik-cache
I/dalvikvm(2373): Unable to open or create cache for /system/app/Test.apk (/data/dalvik-cache/system@app@Test.apk@classes.dex)
D/AndroidRuntime(2373): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm(2373): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41607ce0)
```

And finally it fails to instantiate the application.

Please Note: I have kept zero compression on apk while recompiling with apk multi-tool or while manually placing classes.dex in archive via winrar.
Also, I did sign apk in both cases.
So how do I add the missing classes to an apk? Source code of application isnt provided by dev.

Comment: I can't believe no one answered this question, it's a good question, and I'm looking for the answer to it right now!